# checkboxs in a telerik report Q2 2012, not showing checked or unchecked. Always remain undetermined

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I got stuck in a problem while developing a web based report using q2 2012 telerik reporting. I placed checkboxes and assigned value through databound fields. (=Field.) The columns bound to checkboxes gives either 1 or 0, consecutively signifies true and false. I assigned 1 for TrueValue and 0 for FalseValue from checkbox property.

Whenver I run report, all the checkboxes shows image of undetermined checkbox, never shows any checked or unchecked boxes. I cross checked, that dataset bound to report is fetching correct values for check boxes.

Can you please help me getting rid of this problem. I couldn't figure out where I went wrong? I did exactly what I read in report documentation,
http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-items-checkbox.html

I am using asp.net 3.5 and sqlserver2008R2.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that example you provided concerns `VARCHAR` columns. I guess if you are binding over 1 and 0, then you are using `BIT` DataType (which would be translated by `true` and `false` in ASP.Net).

So, you should try using `true` instead of 1 and , `false` instead of 0.

Comment: Well, this issue got resolved. I had given TrueValue and FalseValue which is not required in case of bit field. I removed them from designer.cs and it worked. Thanks for taking time to answer.